# Restore from Time Machine after installing Bootcamp

Tags: time-machine, bootcamp, install

Can I setup Time Machine to backup my Mac and then install Bootcamp?
Then after installing Bootcamp, can I go back to that restore point so Bootcamp will be gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Bootcamp will create a fysical partition on your Macintosh HD. If you restore your Mac  with TimeMachine, the software will only detect your Mac-partition and restore it's data. It will leave your Bootcamp partition in tact.

If you want to get rid of the Bootcamp partition, just run the Bootcamp assistant again and it will allow you to delete the Windows partition with one mouseclick.

Comment: Can I put back the deleted Windows partition back to my Mac partition?

Comment: So you're asking for a solution to create a partition, delete it and restore it by a back-up software?

Comment: not really. since im not yet that familiar with my Mac, and I want to try out bootcamp, I just want to know how to restore things the way they were before should my installation of Win7 using bootcamp screw up. And I am anticipating a screw up because I do not have my Mac OS X Lion installer with me (Laptop is company issued), I heard you can install bootcamp/windows 7 without the Mac OS X installer DVD by downloading Apple's drivers on the web.

Comment: If you want to experiment with Windows 7, you can try out one of the virtualisation software. This creates and deleted Windows partitions on the fly. Try VMWare or Parallels to do so.

Comment: I have already tried VMs. But they are slow. And Ill be playing games and using heavy apps on Windows 7 so I guess Bootcamp is the way.

Answer (score 0):

If something goes wrong, simply start Boot Camp Assistant again. You can use it to delete the Windows partition, during which process the Boot Camp Assistant will also (and automatically) merge the deleted partition with the Mac partition. It will do so without you losing any data from the Mac partition (but you will lose *everything* on the Windows partition, of course).

In other words, after you use the Boot Camp Assistant to delete the Windows partition, the partitioning scheme on the drive should be identical to how it was before you used Boot Camp and installed Windows in the first place.